# Problems with setText in a fragment in onCreateView(...)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know that people has asked similar questions but I still can't manage. I have a fragment and in the `onCreateView()` I have a string that I want to set equal to the text in my textView. However I can't make it work. Can somebody please give me a code example of how to write it?

I have for instance tried this which makes the app crash:

```
TextView text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sektion_name_detailed_view);
    text.setText("test");
```

Stacktrace:

```
06-12 23:02:59.926: W/dalvikvm(2402): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at se.Appsolut.student.DetailedViewSektionerFragment.onCreateView(DetailedViewSektionerFragment.java:21)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-12 23:02:59.933: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log please?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275467/android-set-text-to-textview

Comment: You are right it's the same question but the "answers" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is a fragment then you will have to inflate the layout first on `onCreateView` before accessing the elements.

```
LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); 
View view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false); //pass the correct layout name for the fragment

TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sektion_name_detailed_view);
text.setText("Just another sample");
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> My Approach is Little bit Different to set Text in Fragment. Basically I use view Object to set Text in Fragment. Because onCreateView() Return a View Every single Component using inflater Class inflate method. So I have Created a View Object Globally and assign it to inflate method and return it in onCtreateView() Method. So, As a Result TextView Component is already Inside the view So I can use it anywhere i want.

```
View inflatedview = null;

public CustomerOutstanding() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflatedview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_outstanding, container, false);
    TotalAmount = (TextView)inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.TotalAmountOutstanding);

    return inflatedview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using databinding so,

```
binding.sektion_name_detailed_view.text="your_text"
```

or

```
binding.sektion_name_detailed_view.text= resources.getString(R.string.your_text)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think maybe you edit like

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sektion_name_detailed_view);
text.setText("test");
```

Comment: This won't compile.  You need getView().findViewById